# How to remove the chosen product after clicking the button again?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I have a shopping cart and when i click on the button["Add to Cart"], it highlights into color blue and changes its name to ["Added to Cart"]. However i want it to be unhighlighted and change the name back to "Add to Cart". The code is quite long but Im hoping you guys can help me. here is my add to cart button code:

```
protected void btnAddToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ProductID = Convert.ToInt16((((Button)sender).CommandArgument)).ToString();
        string ProductQuantity = "1";

        DataListItem currentItem = (sender as Button).NamingContainer as DataListItem;
        Label lblAvailableStock = currentItem.FindControl("lblAvailableStock") as Label;

        if (Session["MyCart"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["MyCart"];
            var checkProduct = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("ProductID") == ProductID); // check whether product is already added or not
            if (checkProduct.Count() == 0)
            {
                string query = "select * from Products where ProductID = " + ProductID + "";
                DataTable dtProducts = GetData(query);

                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["ProductID"] = ProductID;
                dr["Name"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["Name"]);
                dr["Description"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["Description"]);
                dr["Price"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["Price"]);
                dr["ImageUrl"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["ImageUrl"]);
                dr["ProductQuantity"] = ProductQuantity;
                dr["AvailableStock"] = lblAvailableStock.Text;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                Session["MyCart"] = dt;
                btnIslandGas.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                if (checkProduct.Count() != 0)
                {
                    var ProductRowToBeDeleted = dt.Select("ProductID =" + ProductID);
                    foreach (var row in ProductRowToBeDeleted)
                    {
                        row.Delete();
                        btnIslandGas.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string query = "select * from Products where ProductID = " + ProductID + "";
            DataTable dtProducts = GetData(query);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //storing all of the records

            dt.Columns.Add("ProductID", typeof(string)); // adding the columns
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ImageUrl", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductQuantity", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("AvailableStock", typeof(string));

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); //adding the rows
            dr["ProductID"] = ProductID;
            dr["Name"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["Name"]);
            dr["Description"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["Description"]);
            dr["Price"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["Price"]);
            dr["ImageUrl"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["ImageUrl"]);
            dr["ProductQuantity"] = ProductQuantity;
            dr["AvailableStock"] = lblAvailableStock.Text;  

            dt.Rows.Add(dr); //adding the data row in the data table. 

            Session["MyCart"] = dt; //asigning the datatable in the session.
            btnIslandGas.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
        }
        HighLightCartProducts();
    }
```

edited highlight cart code

```
private void HighLightCartProducts()
    {
        if (Session["MyCart"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtProductsAddedToCart = (DataTable)Session["MyCart"];
            if (dtProductsAddedToCart.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataListItem item in dlProducts.Items)
                {
                    HiddenField hfProductID = item.FindControl("hfProductID") as HiddenField; // Getting hidden filed value
                    if (dtProductsAddedToCart.AsEnumerable().Any(row => hfProductID.Value == row.Field<String>("ProductID")))
                    {
                        //item.BackColor =  System.Drawing.Color.Red;

                        Button btnAddToCart = item.FindControl("btnAddToCart") as Button; //item.FinControl finds the item(Button)
                        btnAddToCart.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
                        btnAddToCart.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                        btnAddToCart.Text = "Added to Cart";

                        Image imgGreenstar = item.FindControl("imgStar") as Image;
                        imgGreenstar.Visible = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Button btnAddToCart = item.FindControl("btnAddToCart") as Button;
                        btnAddToCart.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                        btnAddToCart.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                        btnAddToCart.Text = "Add to Cart";
                        Image imgGreenstar = item.FindControl("imgStar") as Image;
                        imgGreenstar.Visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and added remove highlight code

```
private void RemoveHighLightCartProducts(string ProductId)
    {

        if (Session["MyCart"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtProductsAddedToCart = (DataTable)Session["MyCart"];
            //delete row which contains product data.

            var ProductRowToBeDeleted = dtProductsAddedToCart.Select("ProductID =" + ProductId);
            foreach (var row in ProductRowToBeDeleted)
            {
                row.Delete();
            }
            foreach (DataListItem item in dlProducts.Items)
            {


                Button btnAddToCart = item.FindControl("btnAddToCart") as Button;
                btnAddToCart.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                btnAddToCart.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                btnAddToCart.Text = "Add to Cart";
                Image imgGreenstar = item.FindControl("imgStar") as Image;
                imgGreenstar.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The highlight code is one direction only: It checks the session[mycart], so it will always say "added to cart". To "fix" this you would have to see if your cart for example has a timestamp and use this to skip the highlight OR register the highlight in the cart and skip it next time OR use javascript instead of the current C# class to have a transient highlight.

Comment: thanks for the answer and acknowledging. do you have any examples? @NorbertvanNobelen

Answer (score 0):

just add this code in your code, it checks if product is already added to cart, then it removes it from cart and removes highlighting.
and I would suggest to write separate methods for highlighting and for  removing highlight.

```
 protected void btnAddToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ProductID = Convert.ToInt16((((Button)sender).CommandArgument)).ToString();
    string ProductQuantity = "1"; 

    DataListItem currentItem = (sender as Button).NamingContainer as DataListItem;
    Label lblAvailableStock = currentItem.FindControl("lblAvailableStock") as Label;

    if (Session["MyCart"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["MyCart"];
        var checkProduct = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("ProductID") == ProductID); // check whether product is already added or not
        if (checkProduct.Count() == 0)
        {
            string query = "select * from Products where ProductID = " + ProductID + "";
            DataTable dtProducts = GetData(query);

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["ProductID"] = ProductID;
            dr["Name"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["Name"]);
            dr["Description"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["Description"]);
            dr["Price"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["Price"]);
            dr["ImageUrl"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["ImageUrl"]);
            dr["ProductQuantity"] = ProductQuantity;
            dr["AvailableStock"] = lblAvailableStock.Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            Session["MyCart"] = dt;
            btnIslandGas.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
            HighLightCartProducts();
        }
        else
        {
           RemoveHighLightCartProducts(ProductId);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        string query = "select * from Products where ProductID = " + ProductID + "";
        DataTable dtProducts = GetData(query);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //storing all of the records

        dt.Columns.Add("ProductID", typeof(string)); // adding the columns
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ImageUrl", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ProductQuantity", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("AvailableStock", typeof(string));

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); //adding the rows
        dr["ProductID"] = ProductID;
        dr["Name"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["Name"]);
        dr["Description"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["Description"]);
        dr["Price"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["Price"]);
        dr["ImageUrl"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["ImageUrl"]);
        dr["ProductQuantity"] = ProductQuantity;
        dr["AvailableStock"] = lblAvailableStock.Text;  

        dt.Rows.Add(dr); //adding the data row in the data table. 

        Session["MyCart"] = dt; //asigning the datatable in the session.
        btnIslandGas.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
        HighLightCartProducts();
    }

}


private void HighLightCartProducts()
{
    if (Session["MyCart"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dtProductsAddedToCart = (DataTable)Session["MyCart"];
        if (dtProductsAddedToCart.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataListItem item in dlProducts.Items)
            {
                HiddenField hfProductID = item.FindControl("hfProductID") as HiddenField; // Getting hidden filed value
                if (dtProductsAddedToCart.AsEnumerable().Any(row => hfProductID.Value == row.Field<String>("ProductID")))
                {
                    //item.BackColor =  System.Drawing.Color.Red;

                    Button btnAddToCart = item.FindControl("btnAddToCart") as Button; //item.FinControl finds the item(Button)
                    btnAddToCart.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
                    btnAddToCart.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                    btnAddToCart.Text = "Added to Cart";
                    Image imgGreenstar = item.FindControl("imgStar") as Image;
                    imgGreenstar.Visible = true;
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
}


    private void RemoveHighLightCartProducts(string ProductId)
```

{

```
if (Session["MyCart"] != null)
{
    DataTable dtProductsAddedToCart = (DataTable)Session["MyCart"];
    //delete row which contains product data.

    var ProductRowToBeDeleted = dtProductsAddedToCart.Select("ProductID =" + ProductId);
    foreach (var row in ProductRowToBeDeleted)
    {
        row.Delete();
    }
    foreach (DataListItem item in dlProducts.Items)
    {
     //if (dtProductsAddedToCart.AsEnumerable().Any(row => ProductID!=row.Field<String>("ProductID")))
     foreach((DataRow rw in dtProductsAddedToCart.Rows)
     {
        if(rw["ProductID"])!=ProductID)
        {
            Button btnAddToCart = item.FindControl("btnAddToCart") as Button; //item.FinControl finds the item(Button)
            btnAddToCart.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            btnAddToCart.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            btnAddToCart.Text = "Added to Cart";
            Image imgGreenstar = item.FindControl("imgStar") as Image;
            imgGreenstar.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Button btnAddToCart = item.FindControl("btnAddToCart") as Button;
            btnAddToCart.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            btnAddToCart.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            btnAddToCart.Text = "Add to Cart";
            Image imgGreenstar = item.FindControl("imgStar") as Image;
            imgGreenstar.Visible = false;
        }
     }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: hey @learningNew, its working but its like not letting me to remove all of the products. it always has to be one product being added?

Comment: for example i have 4 products and i have added all of them. i am able to remove the highlight from the 3 of them but 1 of them stays highlighted. it cannot be removed.

Comment: Sorry missed "if (dtProductsAddedToCart.Rows.Count > 0)" line , once you remove last product in cart 
//if (dtProductsAddedToCart.Rows.Count > 0)// doesn't let you go to the remove highlight code.
instead of removing product from cart in 'btnAddToCart_Click' event ,remove it in 'highlight method' based on ProductID , after // if (dtProductsAddedToCart.Rows.Count > 0),
then remove highlighting and don't forget to assign  DataTable dtProductsAddedToCart to Session["MyCart"].

Comment: so what code will i add on sir? can you edit your answer? thanks so much!

Comment: hi on the first code under highlight method,  will i add it along with the else part? im confused. @learningNew

Comment: Check the edited answer. Can't try it though(sorry for bad formatting of using Notepad).

Comment: not successfull. its not reading the "dt". the only problem is that the last product remains highlighted and it cannot be unhighlighted

Comment: can you also edit the first code above? the else part in the highlight method pls :)

Comment: replace dt with dtProductsAddedToCart and assign dtProductsAddedToCart to session value at the end of removeHighlight method.

Comment: i copied the last updated answer you gave me. the product is still highighted. how will i assign dtProductsAddedToCart to session value?

Comment: kindly look at my edited query above. thats what i have so far and i can feel that its almost done. :) pls help me @learningNew

Comment: looks like working at first but then when i remove one product, all of the highlighted products are being unhighlighted? really thank you for helping me out @learningNew

Comment: look at my query sir. i think we can go from there. its very close to success. only one product cannot be unhighlighted. im also figuring it out. thank you for your help @learningNew

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod- Check now, if this is not working then I need to find some IDE, and no need to call me sir. :)

Comment: thank you @learningNew. i made all the ProductId into ProductID, is that fine? however i have the same error. it works fine in highlighting products but when i try to remove one product, the highlight turns off for all of the products :(

Comment: @paolo - have corrected the if condition, this should work.

Comment: it has reversed its function @learningNew. highlight is fine but when i try to unhighlight it, all of the products become highlighted. im confused with the ProductId and ProductID, is your given code accurate ? thanks so much

Comment: the closes to success code is the one in my query wherein the only problem is that one item that cannot be highlighted. @newLearning

Comment: still there? @newLearning